# React How to wait till current user data is fetched after user has logged in

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-router-dom

In my react app I have guest routes and protected routes. The protected routes are only accessible when the user is authenticated. Next to that, the main app routes are only accessible when the user has signed a contract and finished the onboarding. I'm keeping track of these steps with some extra properties assigned to the user.

My current flow is the following

1. The user enters the app and the function `fetchCurrentUser` is triggered inside the AuthContext Provider. If the call to the database returns data the property `isAuthenticated` is set to true and the user data is set to the `currentUser` state. If the calls returns an (unauthorized) error `isAuthenticated` is set to false. Initially `isAuthenticated` is set to `null` so I can render a loader as long as `isAuthenticated` is null.
2. Let's assume the user wasn't logged in. Since `isAuthenticated` was first `null` and now `false` the code isn't returning the `<h1>Loading</h1>` loader anymore but will return a route. Because `/` can't be accessed because `isAuthenticated` is false, the app will redirect the user to the `/login` page
3. When the user fills in the credentials and submits the data a cookie is returned from the backend and set in the browser. Now I want to re-trigger the `fetchCurrentUser` function to collect the user information. * To do this I set `isAuthenticated` back to null and I navigate the user to the dashboard page `/`. Since `isAuthenticated` is `null` the spinner will show up instead but the route is already `/`.
4. In the meantime `fetchCurrentUser` will do the api call with the cookie which will return the user data and set `isAuthenticated` to true.

Short note for step 3 and 4. I think there are better ways to handle this so please don't hesitate to share a better solution.

Maybe there is a way to call the `fetchCurrentUser` from the Login component and wait till the data is set and navigate the user afterwards? Because `fetchCurrentUser` is more than an api call and the submit function has to wait till the whole function is done I should work with a promise but inside a promise I can't use async/wait to wait for the api call.

5. Now that `isAuthenticated` is true and the user data is known and stored in the AuthProvider the routes can be rendered again. Since `/` is a protected route the code will check if `isAuthenticated` is true and check to which route the user needs to be navigated. This part goes wrong `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded` but I don't know what I'm missing.

Code to test things out with some fake calls the represent the flow via https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-meitner-9t000f?file=/src/router/index.js

**Login.js**

```
const Login = () => {
    const { setIsAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const resolver = useYupResolver(loginValidationSchema);
    const {
        handleSubmit,
        register,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm({ resolver });

    const submit = async (values) => {
        await authService.login(values);
        setIsAuthenticated(null);
        navigate('/');
    };

    return (
        <div className='w-full border border-grey-300 rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md'>
            <div className='p-4'>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)} className='space-y-6'>
                    <Input type='text' label='email' name='email' register={register} error={errors.email} />
                    <Input type='password' label='password' name='password' register={register} error={errors.password} />
                    <Button type='submit' label='login' color='tenant-primary' />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

**AuthContext**

```
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated !== false) {
            getCurrentUser();
        }
    }, [isAuthenticated]);

    const getCurrentUser = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await authService.me();
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
            setCurrentUser(data);
        } catch (error) {
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
            setCurrentUser(null);
        }
    };

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated, getCurrentUser, currentUser }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};
```

**router.js**

```
const Router = () => {
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

    const GuestRoute = () => {
        return !authContext.isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/' replace />;
    };

    const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
        if (!authContext.isAuthenticated) return <Navigate to='/login' replace />;
        else if (!authContext.currentUser?.settings?.is_contract_signed) return <Navigate to='/contract/sign' replace />;
        else if (!authContext.currentUser?.settings?.is_onboarding_finished) return <Navigate to='/onboarding' replace />;
        else return <Outlet />;
    };

    if (authContext.isAuthenticated === null) {
        return <h1>Loading ...</h1>;
    }

    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route element={<GuestRoute />}>
                <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
            </Route>

            <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
                <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to='/onboarding' replace />} />
                <Route path='/contract/sign' element={<SignContract />} />
                <Route path='/onboarding' element={<Onboarding />} />
                <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
            </Route>

            <Route path='404' element={<NotFound />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/404' replace />} />
        </Routes>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The is caused by the `ProtectedRoutes` unconditionally redirecting to authenticated routes.

```
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  if (!authContext.isAuthenticated)
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;         // <-- here
  else if (!authContext.currentUser?.settings?.is_contract_signed)
    return <Navigate to="/contract/sign" replace />; // <-- here
  else if (!authContext.currentUser?.settings?.is_onboarding_finished)
    return <Navigate to="/onboarding" replace />;    // <-- here
  else return <Outlet />;
};
```

This rerenders the route which rerenders the `ProtectedRoutes` component which triggers another redirect, repeat ad nauseam.

## Solution

The `ProtectedRoutes` component should only concern itself with protecting access to a route ***or*** redirecting to another route to authenticate. The redirecting to specific protected routes based on user properties should occur in the login logic.

Additionally I ***highly*** recommend moving the `GuestRoute` and `ProtectedRoutes` component declarations ***out of*** the `Router` component. When these components are redeclared each render cycle it will necessarily unmount and remount their entire sub-ReactTree.

router/index.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "../pages/Login";
import SignContract from "../pages/SignContract";
import Onboarding from "../pages/Onboarding";
import Dashboard from "../pages/Dashboard";

import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";

const GuestRoute = () => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  return !authContext.isAuthenticated ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/" replace />
  );
};

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  return authContext.isAuthenticated ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" replace />
  );
};

const Router = () => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (authContext.isAuthenticated === null) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<GuestRoute />}>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Route>

      <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" replace />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/contract/sign" element={<SignContract />} />
        <Route path="/onboarding" element={<Onboarding />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

pages/Login.js

The `handleSubmit` handler should receive the returned user object from the auth service and check the "roles" here to redirect to the appropriate authenticated route.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const data = await authService.login(formData);

  if (data) {
    const user = await authService.me();
    if (user) { 
      authContext.setIsAuthenticated(true);
      if (user?.settings?.is_contract_signed) {
        navigate("/contract/sign", {replace: true});
      } else if (user?.settings?.is_onboarding_finished) {
        navigate("/onboarding", {replace: true} );
      } else {
        navigate("/", { replace: true});
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The login logic might also want to implement this in a try/catch to handle any Promise rejections and other thrown errors, and also handle the case where the authentication fails. For example, should there be an error message, or redirect to another special page, etc. Basically this code should handle both the happy and unhappy paths.

[image: Edit react-how-to-wait-till-current-user-data-is-fetched-after-user-has-logged-in]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and updated CodeSandbox. Your solutions will always redirect to the sign contract page because the login function does not return the user settings. The user info and permissions/roles will come from the auth service but will not return the extra settings. These can be received from the a second call to `authService.me()`.

Comment: @Thore Ah, yeah, I see that, just invert the redirect conditions in the login handler, only redirect to these other routes if the user object has those properties set true. Perhaps the `login` function *should* return the user object, but yeah, another call to get the user would work.

Comment: I changed `const user = await authService.login(formData);` to `const data = ...` and the first `if(user)` to `if(data)` and added `const user = await authService.me();` just below the `authService.login` line and it's all working. (Can't change you post because the edit queue is full but others can see the last changes in the comments)

Comment: I'm still not completely where I want to be. I want to limit the access to `contract/sign` and `/onboarding` based on the setting properties. When the user is authenticated and `is_contract_signed` is false only `contract/sign` can be accessed. When the user is authenticated,  is_contract_signed is true and is_onboarding_finished is false only `/onboarding` can be accessed. When both is_contract_signed and is_onboarding_finished are true the user can not access these routes anymore but only the 'real' protected routes. Any advice on how to obtain this?

Comment: @Thore What you describe sort of sounds like "role", or "status", based route protection. You can create more protected route components that specifically check these "roles"/"statuses" to further restrict access beyond the base "isAuthenticated" status. Does this make sense? If you need it I can fork the above sandbox and create a demo.

Comment: I forked your solution again and moved the redirections from the login submit function to the getCurrentUser function in AuthContext so these can also be used when the user is already logged in. Second I added extra route components in the router.js file but with the same method as before that is causing the issue of rerendering the route and keeps redirecting. I would be much appreciated if you can take another look of how this can be handled in a correct way with all the different if/else possibilities. 1/2

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-to-wait-till-current-user-data-is-fetched-after-user-has-logged-in-forked-1tb1fe?file=/src/router/index.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-to-wait-till-current-user-data-is-fetched-after-user-has-logged-in-forked-1tb1fe?file=/src/router/index.js) 2/2

Comment: Are you able to take another look to the above comments?

Comment: @Thore Remove the redirects from the `getCurrentUser` function in the context if you are redirecting elsewhere in the other route protection components.

Answer (score 0):

It shows "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded" because when you call getCurrentUser() method if isAuthenticated not false the method triggered 2 states and React sees that there are two states and React updated two states in the same time (automatic batching) and when isAuthenticated get new value useEffect() works again it sees that isAuthenticated true ant it is again changes states it happens again again and to infinity for that it show that error

Comment: I changed the if inside the useEffect function to `if (currentUser === null && isAuthenticated !== false)`  but I'm still getting the "Maximum update depth exceeded" warning. If I log the values and I get an object for `currentUser` and true for `isAuthenticated` and they both only log once